# Set column type to NCHAR instead of NVARCHAR with IEntityTypeConfiguration

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I'm using EF Core 2.2.x and have a table with 50+ string columns. In my migration I want to set all these to `NCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`. They all have different length. Is there a way to change the SQL-type for all columns at the same time, without manually set it on each column? I want to do this in my `IEntityTypeConfiguration`.

```
public class MyTableConfig : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MyTable>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyTable> entity)
    {

        foreach (var property in entity.Metadata.GetProperties()
            .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string)))
        {
            if (property.GetMaxLength() == null)
                property.SetMaxLength(256);

            // Can it be set from here?

        }

        entity.ToTable("MyTable", "fooSchema");


        entity.Property(e => e.Address1).HasMaxLength(30);
        entity.Property(e => e.Address2).HasMaxLength(20);

        /* A lot of other declarations below */

   }
}
```

I know I can use [`IsFixedLength`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertybuilderextensions.isfixedlength?view=efcore-2.2), but I want to use it on all columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `IsFixedLength` fluent API, in EF 2.x you could use [IsFixedLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.relationalpropertyannotations.isfixedlength?view=efcore-2.2) property of the [RelationalPropertyAnnotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.relationalpropertyannotations?view=efcore-2.2) class returned by [Relational](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalmetadataextensions.relational?view=efcore-2.2) extension method:

```
property.Relational().IsFixedLength = true;
```

In EF Core 3.0+ the same is achieved with [SetIsFixedLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalpropertyextensions.setisfixedlength?view=efcore-3.0) extension method:

```
property.SetIsFixedLength(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MyTable> entity)
{
    foreach (var pb in entity.Metadata.GetProperties()
        .Where(p => p.ClrType == typeof(string))
        .Select(p =>
            new
            {
                PropertyBuilder = entity.Property(p.Name),
                Property = p
            }))
    {
        int length = pb.Property.GetMaxLength() ?? 256;
        pb.PropertyBuilder.HasColumnType($"NCHAR({length})");
    }
}
```